# Seletor não pega outro seletor

Tags: html, css

Tenho um efeito transição em uma **div** que deve ser aplicado quando faço **hover em outra div.**

Tentei usar alguns seletores ( +, >) não consegui acredito que seja o jeito que estou usando eles

```css
.box-toogle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
 top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    transition: top 1s;
background-color: red;
}

.tgl {
 position: relative;
 top: 80px;
}

.cubo {
 background-color: #0078e1;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 4px 7px 22px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 position: relative;
 top: 90px;
 left: 20px;
 z-index: 1;
 transition: 1s;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #eeeeee;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.cubo:hover {
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 color: #0078e1; 
}

.cubo:hover + .box-toogle {
    top: -120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-toogle">
   <h3 class="logo">Planejamento de Viagem</h3>
  <div class="tgl">
   <div >
    <p>t>este</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cubo">X</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual efeito deve ser realizado?

Comment: @Euler01 Movimentação o box-toogle tem que movimentar para cima

Comment: Não use tags que não tem haver com o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fazendo ao contrário. Desse jeito realmente não vai funcionar.
O + na regra css quer dizer "o próximo elemento imediatamente após".
Nesse caso o .cubo não tem mais nenhum elemento após ele é você usa o + apontando para o pai. Por isso não vai funcionar.

Se eu entendi bem, você quer o .cubo quando um evento hover acontecer em .box-toogle, mas escreveu o css invertido.

Então ficaria assim:

```
.box-toogle:hover + .cubo {
    top: -120px;
}
```

A resposta anterior trata de outra coisa.

Comment: Opa irei atualizar e deixar um efeito funcionando para mostrar o que quero

Comment: Obrigado funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Atualize seu CSS para suportar diferentes browsers, Porém, o transitions do CSS3 não é suportado por versões inferiores ao 10 do IE.

Para saber mais, acesse:
[CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Segue o código atualizado:

```
.cubo {
    background-color: #0078e1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 4px 7px 22px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 7px 22px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 7px 22px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, irei fazer isso sim!